# how to implement pooling using android bluetooth chat sample app?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am working on an application that uses BluetoothChat sample application. 
In my main activity I am using a webview in which I load an external page. I am handling Bluetooth functionality via a javascript that loads with the external page. Basically I add a bridge between Javascript and native code via the following line:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this,myWebView), "Android");//I pass a refference to the context and a refference to the webview.
```

WebAppInterface is the class that has all the public methods I can call from Javascript. In this class I have methods like: enableBluetooth, disableBluetooth, listBoundedDevices, connect etc.

I am using BluetoothSerialService class from BluetoothChat sample application. My device has to connect to an embedded device which receives commands and answers back differently depending on the input I give. An example would be like: when I press a button on the webview I call the following native code:

```
while(true){
    out.write(requestKey);//send command - where "out" is the OutputStream
    key = in.read();//get response - where "in" is the InputStream
    if(key==KEY1){
        out.write(activateRFID);//send command - activateRFID
        rfidTag = in.read();//get response - RFID Tag
        updateUI(rfidTag);//perform function - update the UI with the tag 
    }
    else if(key==KEY2){
        out.write(deactivateRFID);//send command  - deactivate RFID
        response = in.read();//get response
    }
    else if(key==KEY3){
        out.write(anotherCommand);//send command  - 
        response = in.read();//get response
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is sending commands to another device(request the pressed key)  and perform functions. This has to happen always (pooling the device for the key pressed and perform a particular function).

How can I start 1 SINGLE THREAD that pools the device (write to the OutputStream and read the response from the InputStream)? The BluetoothChat sample application works a little different: whenever I call BluetoothChatSevice.write() I get a response via ConnectedThread run method that sends messages to UI via a mHandler.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I did it today. I suggest that you do a boolean function readWrite() that whenever you write to outputStream you also read from the inputStream and send the readBuffer to UI with mHandler. If both read and write are ok, than return true, if one of them went wrong than return false and use resetConection before closing your ConnectedThread. See my answer here for the resetConnection. [Application using bluetooth SPP profile not working after update from Android 4.2 to Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420525/application-using-bluetooth-spp-profile-not-working-after-update-from-android-4/19025227#19025227)

But the answer about pooling is the following: 
In the ConnectedThread run() method do a while(true), call a method similar to readWrite(byte[] data) inside the loop, where in the first place you write something to the device, and then you read the data from the input stream (from the device). In this readWrite() method, if writing to outpustream went fine, then continue to read from the inputstream. if you got any data to the input stream, send the data to UI for processing with the mHandler (or do some processing before sending to the UI).

It worked very nice for me.