# BluetoothClient(C#) write delayed while reading from Android client

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, networkstream

I am trying to write the continuous data from bluetoothclient(C# NetworkStream) to Android client (BluetoothSocket). But I observed that C# write is getting blocked , while trying to read data from Android bluetooth socket.This block is not observed if I am not trying to read data from client. Tried using BufferedStream for writing , but still I see the same issue.

C# Bluetooth server Code :

```
NetworkStream _st = _clnt.GetStream();
while(true){
   _st.Write(_serData, 0, _serData.Length);
   // Required delay is given before writing next chunk
}
```

Android Bluetooth reader :

```
InputStream inputstream = btSocket.getInputStream()
while(true){
 int len = inputstream.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length);
 offset += len;
}
```

Comment: You should post some code if you want people to know what you're doing.

Comment: Do you have any clue if this is blocked on android side or server side? I am immediately thinking this could be android permissions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Even more code and specifications of the problem could help too

Comment: Problem I am facing here is delay in writing data(C#) while reading data on other side.

Comment: Post how you are creating the socket on each side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by sending keep-ALive packets from ANdroid client side , solved my problem as suggested in

[Application using bluetooth SPP profile not working after update from Android 4.2 to Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420525/application-using-bluetooth-spp-profile-not-working-after-update-from-android-4)