# Why does Android Wear bluetooth disconnect after some time - btm_sec_disconnected?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I am developing an android app for android wear Android Wear 4.4W. I'm debugging the app directly via usb in the smartwatch (that's how I want it - no companion app on the phone). The app receives bluetooth messages every 10ms. After 10-20s, this error is thrown -

```
01-01 21:10:22.683 E/bt-btm  (  826): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
01-01 21:10:22.686 W/bt-btif (  826): invalid rfc slot id: 4
```

I'm basically using this code- [How to receive serial data using android bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth)

I tried sending "keep alive" messages as mentioned here-
[Application using bluetooth SPP profile not working after update from Android 4.2 to Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420525/application-using-bluetooth-spp-profile-not-working-after-update-from-android-4) , but this does not work either.

Are there any mistakes that I'm making or any workarounds to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. The external bluetooth module kept resetting itself because of some circuit issues. The reset caused the connection to be lost momentarily.